# Find Maximum Value From Multiple Cells and Insert New Row With A Cell That Has The Maximum Value +1

Tags: excel, vba, insert, max

I have 4 sheets, all with a column in the range B15:B1000 with a tracking number that increases with each input. I have 4 macros that inserts a new row in the range B15:W15 on each of the 4 sheets respectively, but I need the inserted row to have the next number that hasn't appeared already in any of the 4 columns as each number can only appear once across all 4 sheets.

So the code I need would have to find the maximum value from all 4 sheets and then insert the new row with the max value plus one in the cell B15. The code I have so far is below and is for only one of the four sheets but uses the same exact layout. Any help would be appreciated!

```
Sub New_Characterisation()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Worksheets("Characterisation").Activate
Range("B15:W15").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Range("B15:W15").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
Selection.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

Range("B15") = Range("B16") + 1

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You can use `maxVal = WorksheetFunction.Max(Arg1,Arg2,...)` to get the max val and you can then search for that value.

Comment: Would I need to activate each worksheet before executing this code and save the found value to compare later? And what would I replace `Arg1,Arg2,...` with?

Comment: Don't use Activate or Select. First set each worksheet to a variable like `Set wk1 = Sheet1` `Set wk2 = Sheet2` ...... and then access the ranges from the worksheets like `maxVal = WorksheetFunction.Max(wk1.Cells(1,1),wk2.Cells(1,1),...)` Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, this works except for sheet 2 for some reason, the code I added is                                                                                                                    `Set wk1 = Sheet1
    Set wk2 = Sheet2
    Set wk3 = Sheet3
    Set wk4 = Sheet4

    MaxVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(wk1.Range("B15:B1000"), wk2.Range("B15:B1000"), wk3.Range("B15:B1000"), wk4.Range("B15:B1000"))` and I also replace the `Range("B16")+1` with `MaxVal + 1`

Comment: Never mind, it was a mistake on my part! It works perfectly, thank you!